# Using Ruby's `or` Keyword When Creating a Variable

Tags: ruby

I recently came across the following Ruby code, which is confusing me:

```
def initialize(kind, street_1, street_2, city, state, postal_code)
  @kind = kind or ''
  @street_1 = street_1 or ''
  @street_2 = street_2 or ''
  @city = city or ''
  @state = state or ''
  @postal_code = postal_code or ''
end
```

I don't understand what role `or` is playing in this code. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: It should be noted that the `or` keyword does not work in this scenario, but the intention is correct - using `||` instead of `or` in this example will produce the desired output.

The `or` keyword in this code implies that if the parameter being assigned to the local variable (i.e. `kind` and `@kind` respectively) is `nil`, then the value of the local variable should be initialized to `''`

Another way to look at this - if I call `Class.new("something", "1800 Wallaby Way", nil, nil, nil, nil)`, then the class will be initialized as such:

```
@kind = "something"
@street_1 = "1800 Wallaby Way"
@street_2 = ''
@city = '
@state = ''
@postal_code = ''
```

Comment: Not just `nil`, but `false` as well (the two values that evaluate to `false` in Ruby)

Comment: Hrm. That makes perfect sense, but doesn't seem to match what I'm seeing when I test this out.

That is, let's say that I change one line of the `initialize` method to instead be: `@state = state or "TX"`. Now let's say that I call `Class.new("something", "1800 Wallaby Way", nil, nil, nil, nil)`.

After doing all of this, if I then call `puts` on `@state`, wouldn't you expect the output to be `TX`. I would, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead the output is blank, indicating that the `or` keyword is *not* taking effect.

My code: https://repl.it/EGO0/0

Comment: It would seem this code is actually written improperly! Since `or` takes lower precedence than `||` in Ruby, it takes the value of `nil`, skipping the comparison entirely! Replacing it with `||` will produce the desired result.

Comment: Ah yes! Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You've got three ways of fixing this. The first is using brackets to make the loose-binding `or` not lose its grip on the values:

```
@kind = (kind or '')
```

The second is to use the strongly-binding `||` equivalent operator:

```
@kind = kind || ''
```

The third option, and this is the best, is to *not care* and just deal:

```
@kind = kind.to_s
```

This way `nil` will be automatically converted to an empty string if that's the behaviour you want.

Comment: Good explanation, but it would be unusual to see #1 (which most Rubiest would regard as inferior to #2). Another option would be `@kind = kind ? kind : ''`. Though longer than the others, it may be more expressive.

Comment: I'm not sure the ternary adds any significant meaning there, and in fact might have one wondering why it's so repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

It is adding in the defaults if the you do not specify every variable when you are creating a new instance of what appears to be an "address" object.

Eg.

```
x = Address.new ()

x.kind == ''

# evaluates to true
```

Comment: Try not to put spaces between method names and their arguments. It can cause big problems.